# .net core converting from utc time to my local time and also taking into consideration daylight savings time

Tags: asp.net-core, datetime, dst

I am currently storing date and time in a database using UTC and was wondering if .net core automatically calculates for daylight savings time switching or do I have to manually implement that in my code based on the day that the time shifts in the specific countries?

I need the database to convert the UTC time in the database to Toronto, Ontario's current date and time.

Comment: please check it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use the TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc method to convert the UTC time to Toronto time.

Details ,you could refer to below codes:

```
  // your datadbase UTC  time
        DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        //time zone  for Toronto
        TimeZoneInfo torontoTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

        // convert the UTC time to Toronto time
        DateTime torontoTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, torontoTimeZone);
```